# Specify an AWS CLI profile in a script when two exist

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm attempting to use a script which automatically creates snapshots of all EBS volumes on an AWS instance. This script is running on several other instances with no issue.

The current instance already has an AWS profile configured which is used for other purposes. My understanding is I should be able to specify the profile my script uses, but I can't get this to work.

I've added a new set of credentials to the `/home/ubuntu/.aws` file by adding the following under the default credentials which are already there:

```
[snapshot_creator]
aws_access_key_id=s;aldkas;dlkas;ldk
aws_secret_access_key=sdoij34895u98jret
```

In the script I have tried adding `AWS_PROFILE=snapshot_creator`but when I run it I get the error `Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".`

So, I delete my changes to `/home/ubuntu/.aws` and instead run `aws configure --profile snapshot_creator`. However after entering all information I get the error `[Errno 17] File exists: '/home/ubuntu/.aws'`.

So I add my changes to the .aws file again and this time in the script for every single command starting with `aws ec2` I add the parameter `--profile snapshot_creator`, but this time when I run the script I get `The config profile (snapshot_creator) could not be found`.

How can I tell the script to use this profile? I don't want to change the environment variables for the instance because of the aforementioned other use of AWS CLI for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credentials should be stored in the file "/home/ubuntu/.aws/credentials"

I guess this error is because it couldn't create a directory. Can you delete the ".aws" file and re-run the configure command? It should create the credentials file under "/home/ubuntu/.aws/"

> File exists: '/home/ubuntu/.aws'

Comment: Deleted that file and re ran the configure command for each profile again and now working as expected. I don't know how that was set up incorrectly, but thanks for that.